# Caffe - How to use reduction layer?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, reduction

I have a question regarding the reduction layer in caffe. I haven't found any examples on how to use this layer in my .prototxt file. So I would appreciate it, if anybody could give me a short example of how to use this layer.

This is the documentation: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1ReductionLayer.html , but there is no example given :-/

I want to use this layer to reduce an output matrix of 1x18x18 to one scalar value. So i want the absolute sum of this matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
layer {
  name: "reduction"
  type: "Reduction"
  bottom: "in"
  top: "out"
  reduction_param {
    axis: 0 # reduce all dims after first
    operation: ASUM  # use absolute sum
  }
}
```

For more information, see [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L956-L983) and the new [caffe.help](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/reduction.html).